# I want to number sentences in InDesign (like Bible verses)

Tags: adobe-indesign

That is, like:

1 ssdfsf sfsfdsf. 2 sfdsffd safdsdff asgg. 3 asdfdsfsag ...

and so forth. Not lines, not paragraphs, not list items, but sentences. (I can accept some manual tinkering.)

If this were HTML, I'd work with CSS to flatten the list items. But it isn't.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think if I could somehow get an incrementing variable into a grep style, I'd be part way there. (A script, perhaps?) But I don't want to be manually search-and-replacing in the breaks; I'm still writing the book!

Comment: No need to check if GREP does this - it does not. InDesign does not have native incremental variables (even page numbering does not work like that). This needs a script. To help it along, consider giving all of your numbers a unique character style (set its color to red or something so you know where it is applied).

Comment: Jongware, I agree that this needs a script. However, I have tinkered in the past with another script that needed to deal with sentences (not paragraphs, not lines) and found it surprisingly hard to figure out via scripting where a sentence starts and ends. What would be a good way to go about this? Some sophisticated GREP?

Comment: @mdomino: there is no good, secure way to have GREP recognize sentences. There are just too many things that can go wrong! Hence my proposal of inserting placeholder numbers marked with a unique style. Those *are* easy to change with a script. Also, it gives the OP a fairly accurate view of what the final text will look like, albeit with the wrong numbers.

Comment: @Jongware: Thanks for you answer. Apart from GREP, do you know *any* secure way to recognize sentences? (And sorry for getting slightly offtopic here).

Comment: @mdomino I think the problem is, nothing but a human can tell if something like "and then Prof. Jeffreys entered" is an abbreviation or a sentence. You could create a convention for using a non-standard character for sentence ending stops, like adding a hair-space or discretionary hyphen after the `.` when it ends a sentence, or (easier to type) a double-space then have another GREP rule that hides the extra space.

Comment: I was going to handle the exceptions manually, by making sure (with invisible characters, say) that they didn't march the grep pattern. But I don't want to batch process this stuff.... So maybe the ingenious footnote solution is the best!

Answer (score 2):

There's a cheeky way you can do this which allows you to insert consistently styled, auto-updating numbers while you type, by **abusing InDesign's "Footnotes" feature**.

Note that InDesign only supports one series of footnotes, so this prevents you from using regular footnotes - however, you can still have actual footnotes in your document using cross-references (in fact, I usually prefer cross-references for footnotes than the footnotes feature anyway since they offer more flexibility in where the note goes, and can be used in more contexts such as inside tables).

1. First, you'll want to use `Edit > Keyboard shortcuts...` to create a keyboard shortcut for `Type > Insert footnote`, since you'll need to get into the habit of using it before each sentence. As discussed in the comments, whatever option you use for this you'll need to manually insert some kind of special marker to discriminate between, for example, `.`s used for sentences and `.`s used for awkward cases like abbreviations that happen to be followed by a capital letter or number, ellipses which may or may not end sentences, sentences inside quotations... There are plenty of possible awkward cases which will require human judgement.
2. Then you'll want to configure `Type > Document footnote options` to style and format your paragraph numbers appropriately, so it looks like sentence numbers, and so the "notes" themselves are hidden. Here's a crude example:

[image]

[image]

3. Then just type. From here on, it'll instantly put in the correctly numbered, correctly styled sentence number each time you use that keyboard shortcut, and it'll instantly update automatically update all the numbers any time you move or delete one. As always when using one of Adobe's automation options, save often, they do sometimes crash.

(for the "invisible" paragraph style, I use `leading: 0`, `font-size: 0.1`, `color: paper` - there might be a better way)

Advantages of this:

- You've got complete control over where every sentence number is placed, so you can handle exceptions and awkward cases like abbreviations, ellipses and sentences within quotations however you choose case-by-case
- The numbering updates live, instantly, if you add, delete or move sentences
- You can update both the character style and the text format of all numbers at once instantly (e.g. roman numerals, letters, 01 02 03 etc etc as well as any suffixes and prefixes)
- It applies live, instantly, as you type, rather than something like a script or action you apply when you've finished

Disadvantages:

- You'll need to get into the habit of doing the keyboard shortcut when typing sentences - but I think you'll need some sort of manually applied sentence marker however you do it, and one press of a keyboard shortcut which instantly creates the correctly styled number is much easier than, say, selecting some text and applying a character style, or adding an invisible character which you might accidentally miss or apply twice.

Comment: Thanks! This might be the best solution... I guess I can go back and retrofit my existing content but that seems like it only requires mere repetition! And adding.... How do you do footnotes with cross references?!

Comment: @shunting if you search on how to do endnotes in InDesign (which isn't normally possible), you'll find some guides on how to use cross references to act like endnotes - these methods can be adapted to act like footnotes